# Working of `useState` function inside `useEffect` function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use `useState` inside `useEffect`. I want to access and modify a state inside it( `useEffect` ), here named as `isAuth` and according to the new state render the component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Authentication = () => {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isAuth);
        setIsAuth(true);
        console.log(isAuth);
    }, [isAuth]);
    return <div>{isAuth ? <p>True</p> : <p>False</p>}</div>;
};

export default Authentication;
```

The thing is in console I am getting `false`, `false`, `true`, `true`.Instead of this console, I expected the 2nd console message to be true. Can someone explain it how it happens and how do I actually change the state before component renders?

Answer (score 7):

`setIsAuth` doesn't cause the local variable`isAuth` to change its value. `const` data values can't be changed, and even if you defined it as `let`, that's not what setting state does. Instead, when you set state, the component rerenders. On that new render, the call to `useState` will return the new value, and you can use that new value for the new render.

The component renders for the first time. Then it runs the effect. The closure for the effect has the local variables from that first render, and your code uses those variables to log the false twice. Since you called set state, a new render will happen, and that new render will have different variables. When it's effect runs, it will log true twice, since that's the values in its closure.

Comment: "Effects always “see” props and state from the render they were defined in."  therefore each render has its own props and state. I recommend reading this for more info: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: ok, I thing what you are trying to say is that the component renders for the first time without executing the `setState` function.Is it right?

Comment: The component renders for the first time. Then it runs the effect. The closure for the effect has the local variables from that first render, and your code uses those variables to log the false twice. Since you called set state, a new render will happen, and that new renderwill have different variables. When it's effect runs, it will log true twice, since that's the values in its closure.

Comment: Thanks :)  for your explanation, I have got the point you are trying to make but can you tell me is there any way by which I can change my default state before rendering it for the first time.

Comment: Well, you can pass a different value to useState. Is that what you mean? If this requires some synchronous calculation, then just do it in the body of the component before calling useState. If it requires async calculation, then you can't do it, not with a single component. You could have a wrapper component though that does the async work, and only once that work is done does it render a child component and pass it a prop. Since the child is never rendered until that prop is available, the child will have it from its first render.

Comment: Thanks again, yeah it was about doing both, some async and some sync work. Have figured it out now of how to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some comments in the code explaining how React `setState` will only update the local const once the component re-renders

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Authentication = () => {
    // React will initialise `isAuth` as false
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Console log outputs the initial value, `false`
        console.log(isAuth);
        // React sets state to true, but the new state is not available until
        // `useState` is called on the next render
        setIsAuth(true);

        // `isAuth` will remain false until the component re-renders
        // So console.log will output `false` again the first time this is called
        console.log(isAuth);
    }, [isAuth]);

    // The first time this is rendered it will output <p>False</p>

    // There will be a re-render after the `setState` call and it will
    // output <p>True</p> 
    return <div>{isAuth ? <p>True</p> : <p>False</p>}</div>;
};

export default Authentication;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's actually correct. `useEffect` lets you access the latest state after an update. So during the first render, what you see is basically the initial state, no matter if you update it.

Calling `setState` inside `useEffect` will cause a rerender with the new state (`isAuth = true`), which will result in calling useEffect again. At this point, the new logged state is true.